# Windows 8 wants to reactivate with new motherboard, error 0x80070241

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

An HP tech had to replace my motherboard (twice within a short period, actually) and now Windows 8 wants me to reactivate. I get this error when I try to go through the activation process:

[image]

What do I do?

---

**Update**: I got this output when I ran the first command in magicandre1981's post.

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Image Version: 6.2.9200.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 1392

The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I also called Microsoft tech support and I gave them my key and the error code, but they directed me towards the DreamSpark site because I'm using a DreamSpark Premium key. I don't know if either of these two actions did anything to resolve the problem, but a few hours later my Windows install had been activated successfully in the background.

This notification showed up in my Action Center, but I don't know if it is related to my problems at all:

[image]

Following this notification I rebooted my machine as instructed and everything seems to work fine now. I'm not sure who to credit for solving this question, though.

Comment: You fixed it yourself by allowing Windows to detect the damage to itself.  Since Andre caused that to happen I suggest you accept his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the new [DISM commands](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx), to detect missing and corrupted Windows files, from a cmd prompt with admin rights:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
```

If it detects errors, run this:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

to restore damaged files. Now reboot and try to activate Windows again. Does it work this time?

Comment: I got [this](http://pastebin.com/WR3DCKcX) output when I ran the first command. I also talked to Microsoft on the phone. They ended up directing me to the DreamSpark website (because I got my key from DreamSpark Premium), but Windows appears to have activated itself correctly in the meantime. Not sure whose answer I should credit... I do have a separate issue where I'm getting code 52 on my iPod driver. Could this be related?

Comment: "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" You should also run chkdsk to fix NTFS issues. Because of HDD issues some Windows files were damaged and this seams to prevent the activation.

Comment: As indicated in my post update, I got [this notification](http://i.imgur.com/U97tv.png) in my Action Center. I let Windows 8 do its thing. The problem (and a possibly related problem with code 52 on a signed device driver) have since disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you activate by phone by following the steps below:

> 1. Press Windows key + X then click Run, then type:   slui.exe  4
> 2. Next press the 'ENTER' key
> 3. Select your 'Country' from the list.
> 4. Choose the 'Phone Activation' option.
> 5. Stay on the phone (do not select/press any options) and wait for a person to help you with activation.
> 6. Explain your problem clearly to the support person.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-pro-upgrade-product-key-cant-be-used-to/1726d238-98fb-4634-a468-04645a8ee097)

Comment: I got [this](http://pastebin.com/WR3DCKcX) output when I ran the first command in magicandre1981's post. I also talked to Microsoft on the phone. They ended up directing me to the DreamSpark website (because I got my key from DreamSpark Premium), but Windows appears to have activated itself correctly in the meantime. Not sure whose answer I should credit... I had tried `slui 4` before but that gave me an error message I don't remember. The "Provide these numbers when you're asked" section was empty at that time.

Comment: @Pieter - Update the question with the content of the pastebin.

Comment: Yeah, probably a better idea. I've updated the post.